# My view not separate data by use pagination

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I use pagination for separate data in the view page it's show the links for select page but it's show all data in database (250 data) it's not separate 30 per page. Please Help me

This my model

```
function get_item_code($param){

    $result = array();
    $sql = "select ic.id, ic.item_code, ic.description, maxdt.maxdt, lc.balance,lc.dt ";
    $sql .= "from tbl_item_code ic ";
    $sql .= "left join ( tbl_lines_code lc inner join ( select id, max(dt) maxdt from tbl_lines_code where active = 1 group by id ) maxdt ";
    $sql .= "on lc.id = maxdt.id and lc.dt = maxdt.maxdt ) on ic.id = lc.id ";
    $sql .= "where ic.active = 1 group by ic.id ";
    // echo $sql;
    if ($param->limit > 0)
        $this->db->limit($param->per_page, $param->limit);
    else
        $this->db->limit($param->per_page);
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $query->result();
    }
    return $result;     
}
```

This my controller

```
public function main(){
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $page = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $param = new stdClass();
    if (!isset($page) || $page == '') {
        $page = 1;
    }
    $param->per_page = 30;
    $param->limit = ($page - 1) * $param->per_page;

    $paginate_url = site_url('warehouse/main');
    $data['total_result'] = $this->m_stock->count_stock ();
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $config['num_links'] = 4;
    $config['base_url'] = $paginate_url;
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['total_result'];
    $config['per_page'] = $param->per_page;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination']   = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['item'] = $this->m_stock->get_item_code($param);
    $this->load->view('v_all_stocks', $data);
}
```

and this my view foe echo `$pagination`

```
<?php 
    if(isset($pagination) && $pagination != ''){
?>
<div class="search_pagination"><?php echo $pagination; ?></div>
<?php }   ?>
```

and use `foreach` for show data

Comment: Use limit with offset like this.  "SELECT * FROM xyz LIMIT 15, 10";

Comment: what you get by this?? `get_item_code`??

Answer (score 0):

**In controller**

```
function main()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $count = $this->m_stock->count_stock();
    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'warehouse/main/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $count;
    $config['per_page'] = 30;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $limit = $config['per_page'];

    // Bootstrap style
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] = false;
    $config['last_link'] = false;
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['item'] = $this->m_stock->get_item_code($limit,$page);//pass item code here

    $this->load->view('v_all_stocks', $data);
}
```

**In model**

```
function get_item_code($limit,$page)
{

    $sql = "select ic.id, ic.item_code, ic.description, maxdt.maxdt, lc.balance,lc.dt ";
    $sql .= "from tbl_item_code ic ";
    $sql .= "left join ( tbl_lines_code lc inner join ( select id, max(dt) maxdt from tbl_lines_code where active = 1 group by id ) maxdt ";
    $sql .= "on lc.id = maxdt.id and lc.dt = maxdt.maxdt ) on ic.id = lc.id ";
    $sql .= "where ic.active = 1 group by ic.id ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT $page, $limit";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```